# Matplotlib extent with mollweide projection

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm having some issues with matplotlib and projecting an array into a Mollweide projection. I'm using Python 3.6 and matplotlib 2.0.2

I have a np.array of shape (360, 180) and I cannot figure out how to get it to plot properly.

For example

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='mollweide')
arr = np.zeros((360, 180))
extent=(-np.pi, np.pi, -np.pi/2., np.pi/2.)
im = ax.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
     extent=extent, aspect=0.5)
```

Produces a blank image. Changing the extent to be in degrees:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='mollweide')
arr = np.zeros((360, 180))
extent=(-180, 180, -180/2., 180/2.)
im = ax.imshow(arr, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
     extent=extent, aspect=0.5)
```

Produces this image [Matplotlib image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcWIR.png). Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing an image with `plt.imshow` on a non-cartesian projection will mostly fail. What is possible however is to use a `pcolormesh`. The mollweide projection would require the coordinates in the range `-π,π` and `-π/2., π/2`. You can hence create a respective grid with `numpy.meshgrid` and plot the array on it with `pcolormesh`. (Note that the y/latitude is the first dimension of that array.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='mollweide')
arr = np.random.rand(180, 360)

lon = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi,360)
lat = np.linspace(-np.pi/2., np.pi/2.,180)
Lon,Lat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

im = ax.pcolormesh(Lon,Lat,arr, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

plt.show()
```

[image]